# C++ scope and Google V8 script context

Tags: c++, scope, v8, embedded-v8, libv8

I have the following, almost working piece of code written in c++:

```
[..]

Handle<Object> jsGlobal;
Handle<Function> jsUpdateFunc;

void setupJs () {
    V8::Initialize();
    Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New();
    Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
    HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
    Local<Context> context = Context::New(isolate);
    Context::Scope context_scope(context);
    Local<String> source = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "var a = 0; function test() { a++; return a.toString(); }");
    Local<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);
    script->Run();

    jsGlobal = context->Global();
    Handle<Value> value = jsGlobal->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "test"));
    jsUpdateFunc = Handle<Function>::Cast(value);
}

void callJs() {
    Handle<Value> args[0];
    Handle<Value> js_result = jsUpdateFunc->Call(jsGlobal, 0, args);
    js_result->ToString();

    String::Utf8Value utf8(js_result);
    printf("%s\n", *utf8);
}

[..]
```

I have the function setupJs() setup the v8 environment and callJs is supposed to be called multiple times (when working, the javascript script increments var a by one each time).

If i put

```
Handle<Value> args[0];
Handle<Value> js_result = jsUpdateFunc->Call(jsGlobal, 0, args);
js_result->ToString();

String::Utf8Value utf8(js_result);
printf("%s\n", *utf8);
```

in setupJs, I can see how the function s called and "1" is printed. But if I leave the function call withing a different function to be called later, i have a Segfault at the line `Handle<Value> js_result = jsUpdateFunc->Call(jsGlobal, 0, args);`

I've checked and both jsUpdateFunc and jsGlobal are not-null pointers

Answer (score 7):

You need to use persistent handles for `jsGlobal` and `jsUpdateFunc`. A normal (local) handle becomes invalid when its enclosing `v8::HandleScope` is destroyed.

You'll also want a global variable for the `v8::Isolate` pointer and another one for a persistent handle to the `v8::Context`.

To call the the script function later, you need to:

1. Lock the isolate (which you really should do in `setupJs` as well; see `v8::Locker`)
2. Enter the isolate (see `v8::Isolate::Scope`).
3. Establish a handle scope (see `v8::HandleScope`).
4. Create a local handle for the context.
5. Enter the context (see `v8::Context::Scope`).
6. Create local handles for `jsGlobal` and `jsUpdateFunc`.
7. Call the script function as above.

Look for `v8::Persistent` and related templates in the V8 header file.